# SOAP WSDL accessible in SoapUI, not in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, soap, wsdl, soapui

I'm attempting to integrate a SOAP web service into my C# project via "Add Service Reference," as I have done successfully at least once before. The address works normally in SoapUI, and even entering the address in a browser brings up the WSDL file as expected. But when I enter the address in the Add Service Reference dialog, it results in an error.

> The document at the url [redacted].com/uesas/WebService/Onboard-2_0.cfc?wsdl was not
>   recognized as a known document type. The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
>
> - Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The root element of a W3C XML Schema should be  and its namespace should be 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.'.
> - Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Discovery document at the URL [redacted].com/uesas/WebService/Onboard-2_0.cfc?wsdl could
>     not be found.'.
>
>   - The document format is not recognized.
> - Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (2, 129).'.
>
>   - The string 'http ://webservice.uesas._[redacted].webroot' is not a valid Uri value.
>
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: '[redacted].com/uesas/WebService/Onboard-2_0.cfc?wsdl'.
>   The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were:

... followed by the first several lines of what is clearly HTML code, instead of WSDL code. So evidently, VS doesn't even SEE the WSDL file, even though SoapUI and any standard browser confirm it's there. Does anyone have any thoughts why this would be?

Comment: I've tried to register my issue with the vendor, but apparently they only use SoapUI internally, so I'm on my own with my Visual Studio issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **?WSDL** after the endpoint address like: `http://localhost:8088/mock_service?WSDL`

Comment: This is a super-old thread, so I can't verify anymore, but that is almost certainly the answer. Accepted!